# Excel VBA - Using the column of one variable range to set another

Tags: excel, vba, variables, foreach, range

I have one variable range object that needs to be set using the column of another range variable. The code sample looks like this:

```
 For Each CCount In Range("'Req Raw'!$A$2:$AA$2")
 If CCount.Value <> 0 And CCount.Value <> "" Then
     Set MCell = Range("'Req Raw'!" & CCount.Column & (RC + 1))
```

I'm quite sure the syntax in the last line is completely wrong and is probably what is causing a Run Time '1004' Error

The break down of what I am trying to do follows:

I have a table of undefined columns and rows. On each `For Each` iteration, I need to set `MCell = Range` to `CCount`'s column and an integer row value.

I have tried using an integer counter for the columns to make the line look like

`Set MCell = Range(Cells(CC, RC + 1))` where CC is an integer but it throws the same error.

Comment: Just checking - in your actual Macro, do you have it `**CCount.Column**`, or is that an emphasis for SO?  I assume as well you define RC somewhere else in your macro, and it is an integer?

Comment: Assuming `RC` is a valid number: `Set MCell = Sheets("Req Raw").Cells(RC + 1, CCount.Column)`

Comment: It's some formatting characters from this site then didn't work. I don't have the **s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
Set MCell = Cells(RC + 1, CCount.Column)
```

Your options do not work, because:

1. `CCount.Column` returns a column number (not a letter), so the result of `CCount.Column & (RC + 1)` could be "12" instead of "A2".
2. In `Cells()` the first argument is Row number and the second is Column number, so this might be the reason why `Set MCell = Range(Cells(CC, RC + 1))` was not working. Another thing here is that you set your range in both functions (`Range` and `Cells`). You should keep one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `set mcell= worksheets("Req Raw").cells(cc,rc+1)`.

Problem with first attempt: You need to convert column number to letter(s) which is complicated when it results multiple letters.
Second attempt: You haven't specified the worksheet.